# mysql select rows not in time period (defined by two columns)

Tags: mysql, sql

The issue looks like that:

I have a table with classes , each has start_time and end_time (stored as INT - minutes, eg 120 - 2:00, 130 - 2:10), what I need to do is to take selected by user classes and filter rest of them to retrive classes that do not collide with selected. Can anyone help with this ? Maybe some clue?

sample rows:

```
id start end
1   0    100
2   50   150
3   160  200
4   50   150
5   50   100
6   200  300
```

if I have selected id=1 then it should return row 3,6 (it covers with 2,4,5 between 50 and 100 so it's impossible to participate in both classes)

if I have selected id=2,6 then it should return row 3

if I have selected id=2 then it should return rows 3,6

if I have selected id=6 then it should return rows 1,2,3,4,5

if I have selected id=3 then it should return rows 1,2

Comment: Could you add sample rows and expected output to the question?

Comment: sample and expected output added

Comment: "if I have selected id=3 then it should return rows 1,2 (they are out of id=3 time range)", isn't 2 inside the range of 3?

Comment: Do you have the possibility of one id appearing multiple times in the table?

Comment: yup, mistake, fixed, sorry for that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That gives overlapping ids for one given id:

```
select id from classes c
inner join classes noc on noc.id = <given id>
where c.start > noc.end or c.end < noc.start
;
```

EDIT:

As far as I understood the extended examples now, you want to give arbitrary subsets of ids as input and want to have all ids which don't overlap with any of them. Let's try:

```
select c.* 
from classes c 
left join classes noc on noc.id in (<idlist>) 
     and noc.start < c.end 
     and noc.end > c.start 
where noc.id is null;
```

The "<" and ">" might be "<=" and ">=" depending on meaning of "overlap".

You do not sound like searching for subclasses, but I think you will find your way through the set-djungle! ;-)

Your example "selected id=3" gives 1,2,4,5,6 to me, because 3 overlaps with no one.

Explanation:

- Go through classes
- Look for classes that overlap with the given classes
- And show me only those classes where no overlapping class is found.

The `noc` stands for "not allowed class". If that class is found, there exists an overlapping to your given set.

Comment: thank You a lot, I added just DISTINCT and removed selected blocks from result so it looks finally like that: 
SELECT DISTINCT b.id
FROM `blocks` b
INNER JOIN `blocks` noc ON noc.id
IN ( 3, 5 )
WHERE (
b.time_start > noc.time_end
OR b.time_end < noc.time_start
)
AND b.id NOT
IN ( 3, 5 )
LIMIT 0 , 30

Comment: Well - I don't understand _that_ answer, but as long as I could help... I thought you provide id 1 and look for 3, but do you want to have all the pairs? You want to remove overlappings?

Comment: ok, but what if I have the other classes at the same time as one I've already chosen ? example. I have classes 1. 100 - 200 2. 200-300 3. 300-400 4. 100-200  and chosen 1 ? how to get only 2 and 3 ?

Comment: Please: Extend your example in your question (EDIT) and give more a list and background what you need. I'll look tomorrow, now it's too late.

Comment: His answer does only return 2 and 3 in the scenario you suggested.

Comment: My point is that if I have only one <given id> it works fine, but when I get few id's there, there is a problem, why? Because join does cartesian product of selected id's and rest, so if in selected it works fine with first, second ... it may not work correct with third (I mean here it should be excluded but it stay's in the result because it meets conditions for third id) and it crashes my result :| Any idea how to fix this ?

Comment: why do I need that "where noc.id is null" ??

Answer (score 3):

Based on hardly anything other than assuming one table as you stated, you will need a self join:

```
SELECT rest.*
FROM classes AS chosen
RIGHT JOIN classes AS rest
    ON rest.start_time NOT BETWEEN chosen.start_time AND chosen.end_time
    AND rest.end_time NOT BETWEEN chosen.start_time AND chosen.end_time
WHERE chosen.ClassID = '4'
```

I've aliased the tables as 'chosen' for chosen class, and 'rest' for the rest of the class list.  This will return all the 'rest' of the classes that don't overlap your chosen class mentioned in the WHERE clause.

Comment: This will not catch collisions between intervals where one completely overrides the other. Example: `rest: (0,300)` and `chosen: (100,200)`

Comment: Good call, flaschenpost has a better answer all around, I've got some friday brain.